# Is a Hopf algebra a group object of some category?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories

The page of ncatlab on [group object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object) states that:

> A group object in $\mathrm{CRing}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is a commutative Hopf
> algebra.

**Question:** Is a (noncommutative) Hopf algebra a group object of some category?
[let assume finite dimensional, if necessary.]

The page of Wikipedia on [group object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object) states that:

> Hopf algebras can be seen as a generalization of group objects to
> monoidal categories.

It is not clear to me how this sentence answers the above question.

Comment: You may be interested in [this new question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/394170/34538).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not with their definition, where they assume the underlying category to be cartesian. You can define a notion of "Hopf object" in arbitrary symmetric monoidal categories, where you also need to specify the existence of a coproduct map. It's a matter of taste, but I think this general definition should actually be called "group object", so that Hopf algebras would be group objects in the category of vector spaces. The basic observation is that in a cartesian category, every object have a unique coalgebra structure given by the "diagonal" map so this part of the structure is forced in that case, so that those definitions are compatible.

Answer (score 7):

Cocommutative Hopf algebras are group objects in the cartesian category of cocommutative coalgebras. There is no such description in the non-cocommutative case. Also since the antipode does not need to be invertible, which is certainly true for group objects.

Comment: Cocommutative, _counital_ coalgebras, though I guess that's a standard assumption.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes it's standard.