# Are the prime number objects given by the prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ct.category-theory, prime-numbers, group-schemes

There is a way to define the notion of prime number in the framework of group theory, thanks to the following observation:
*Observation*: A non-trivial group $G$ is cyclic of prime order iff for any subgroup $K \le G$ then $K=1$ or $G$.

Now the notion of group and subgroup can be [internalized](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internalization) to any category (see [group object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object) and [subobject](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject)). Then, using the above observation, we can internalize the notion of prime number to any category, and call it *prime number object*.

More precisely, let $C$ be a category with binary products and a terminal object $*$. Let $\operatorname{Grp}(C)$ be the category of group objects in $C$. An object $G$ in $\operatorname{Grp}(C)$ is
called a *prime number object* in $C$ if for any monomorphism in $\operatorname{Grp}(C)$, $i: H \hookrightarrow G$, then  $H=*$ or $i$ is an isomorphism.

**Question**: Is a prime number object always given by the data of a prime number (or a set of prime numbers)?

*Remark 1*: My guess is yes, but if we relax the notion of *group object* with the notion of *Hopf object* (as suggested in [Adrien's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393744/34538) to [Is a Hopf algebra a group object of some category?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393743/is-a-hopf-algebra-a-group-object-of-some-category)) then I expect the question to become open and hard (see [Is there a non-trivial Hopf algebra without left coideal subalgebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/192033/34538)).

*Remark 2*: We can also define the notion of *natural number object* (eventually relaxed as above) using the fact that a group is finite iff its [subgroup lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups) is finite, and [Ore's theorem](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1546048) stating that a finite group is cyclic iff its subgroup lattice is distributive.

Comment: Can you please make precise your definition of a prime number object? Also, what do you assume about your category? (I have a guess, but with that definition your question is not well-defined.)

Comment: As @MartinBrandenburg says, this depends on your definitions. A simple example: consider the category of sets-with-an-involution-$\tau$. Then prime number objects will be groups $G$ with an involutive group automorphism $\tau:G\to G$ such that for any $g\in G$ with $g\ne1$, $G$ is generated by $g$ and by $\tau g$. On the other hand you have in this category the notion of object of subgroup objects. This is the involutive set of *all* (not necessarily involutive) subgroups, so if you impose condition that this object reduces to $\{1,G\}$, then you indeed get only "ordinary" primes.

Comment: No in fact in the last case each prime $p$ except $2$ will be represented twice: one with trivial involution of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and another with $\tau(x)=-x$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Done! Is it ok for you?

Comment: The definition is still not correct, namely 1) I guess you want a prime number object to be an object of $C$ (the underlying object of a group object, I guess), not of $\mathrm{Grp}(C)$, 2) your question if a prime number object is a set of prime numbers is not well-defined (how can an object of an abstract category be a set of prime numbers?).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: $Grp(C)$ is the category of group objects in $C$. Next, « given by the data of » is different from « is ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is very vague as it never says what it means by "given by the data of a prime number". Though I think the following example should convince anyone that classyfing such "prime number object" can be much more complicated than listing prime numbers.

Take $K$ to be a fixed group and $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of $K$-sets (i.e. sets with an action of $K$).

A group object of $\mathcal{C}$ is a group with an action of $K$, and any irreducible representation of $K$ on a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-vector space give you such a "prime number object".

In particular such objects contain much more information than just a prime numbers: their numbers of elements is in general a prime power (or infinite) and a group $K$ can have many different irreducible representations in characteristic $p$, even of the same cardinality.

Note that there might be other kind of "prime number object" in that category that are not even "attached" to a prime number in any reasonable sense: if $K = \mathbb{Q}^*$ is the multiplicative group of rational, then $\mathbb{Q}$ with its natural action of $\mathbb{Q}^*$ and its additive group structure is a "prime number object" in $K$-sets. And it is not related to any prime number.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in your last example, $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \mathbb{Q})$ can be replaced by 
$(\mathbb{K}^*,\mathbb{K})$, with $\mathbb{K}$ any field, or even any [division ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring). If I am not mistaken, a ring is a division ring iff it is a left simple ring; so I don't think that we can generalize further.